# Stereo calibration between normal camera and telecentric camera

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

I have 2 cameras, one follows pin hole model and the other has telecentric lens. I want to determine R,t between these two cameras. Is calibration through OpenCV's stereocalibration still applicable?

Comment: telecentric meaning orthogonal projection? I am reasonably sure that *that* will cause trouble. you can't tell how far away anything is, so that will remain a degree of freedom. do literature research (books etc). someone probably thought about the problem before.

Comment: Yes, orthogonal projection. Is there reason x'Fx=0 won't hold?

Comment: on an Halcon site they tell thst their functions wiork for telecentric lenses as well, but they dont mention the formulas. For me this sounds like it migjt only work for telecentric + telecentric or pinhole + pinhole but not the mix. But I didnt check the formulas...

Comment: well some formulas will still hold but *calibration* will be tricky, because of the aforementioned degree of freedom that *can't* be determined from "looking through" the telecentric camera. the usual hartley & zisserman book doesn't mention telecentric lenses at all. halcon docs mention this degree of freedom and discuss it: https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/calibrate_cameras.html

Comment: intrinsic calibration with halcon: https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/11/en/camera_calibration.html again, opencv is unaware of telecentric cameras (only pinhole). if you use pinhole calibration anyway, it might work somehow, or it could just fail catastrophically. an "equivalent" pinhole camera would have zero degrees field of view and be infinitely far away.

Comment: I have seen few papers on telecentric camera intrinsic calibration. I'm going to implement that. Like @Micka said, I have only seen telecentric + telecentric or pinhole + pinhole stereo calibration.

Comment: I found this is halcon camera calibration document. "For a mixed setup with projective and telecentric area-scan cameras, the algorithm performs the same four steps as for a setup with projective area-scan cameras. Possible ambiguities during the first step, as described above for the setup with telecentric cameras, can be resolved as long as there exists a chain of observation poses consisting of all perspective cameras and a sufficient number of calibration objects. Here, sufficient number means that each telecentric camera observes at least two calibration objects of this chain."

Comment: Just to make sure, if I do intrinsic calibration of the telecentric camera and just do traditional stereo calibration with intrinsics fixed, it should work right?